# How to make it work datetime datetime strptime

Tags: python, django

can you tell me why it doesn't translate the date into numbers?

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db import models


def end_date():
    return datetime.date.today() + timedelta(days=7)

def convert_date_str(add_date):
    return datetime.strftime(add_date, "%m/%m/%Y")


class add(models.Model):
    add_date = models.DateField('Дата додавання', auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateField('Дата здачі', default=end_date)
```

as I do not output from the DB string month

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Where are you calling those functions?

Comment: models.py, i need to post the date in html format 01/02/1999

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `strftime` needs to be called on a `datetime` object so you need to enclose your addition statement in brackets.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def end_date(): 
    return (datetime.today() + timedelta(days=7)).strftime("%d %B, %Y")
```

`strptime` is under `datetime.datetime` so you are going too deep. In any case, your second function doesn't make sense. You can only `strptime` from a string, not a `datetime` object. You also shouldn't use the same function and variable names. If you are trying to translate a datestring like `31/01/1999` to a `datetime` object, you can do

```
def convert_to_datetime(date_str):
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Your function names should also be more descriptive because at the moment I don't think any of them describes its actual functionality.

Comment: i try to turn the object into a date string

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting an Attribute error because `timedelta` has no `strftime` method. what you want is:

```py
def end_date():
    # add date object to timedelta first then get string
    return (datetime.date.today() + timedelta(days=7)).strftime("%d %B, %Y")
```

second, `strptime` method takes a string and makes a `datetime` object. `add_date` is a `date` object not a string

```py
def add_date():
    add_date = datetime.date.today()  # <-- this should be a string for strptime to work
    # whats dt in your example?, also strptime argument must be a string
    data_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(add_date, "%d %B, %Y").date()
    return  data_object
```